# Can you set a default "New Image" size for texture painting & baking?

Tags: image, customization, uv-image-editor

Is there a way, either in User Prefs or by saving a startup file, to change the default New Image size to something other than 1024? I prefer higher res maps for texture painting & baking.

Comment: I still have the same problem (now 2.81). Every image that I start has to be adjusted in height and width. Can't I teach Blender somehow e.g. to work with 2048x2048 as default?